# Maven doesn't resolve parent POM file

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, relative-path, parent-pom

I have a **parent POM file** and four **child POM files**. The child modules can't resolve the `relativePath` `../pom.xml`.

**Error:**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvwOs.png)

**Project structure:**
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtDck.png)

**man clean install -X:**
[mvn clean install -X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjzEb.png)

**ParentPom:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven 4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>filler</groupId>
    <artifactId>filler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>filler</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>account-service</module>
        <module>lottery-ticket-service</module>
        <module>lottery-service</module>
        <module>service-registry</module>
    </modules>
```

**ChildPom/lottery-ticket-service:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>filler</groupId>
    <artifactId>filler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>lottery-ticket-service</artifactId
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>13</java.version>
</properties>
```

**ChildPom/lottery-service:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>filler</groupId>
    <artifactId>filler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>lottery-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>13</java.version>
</properties>
```

**ChildPom/service-registry:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>filler</groupId>
    <artifactId>filler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>service-registry</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>13</java.version>
</properties>
```

**ChildPom/account-service:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>filler</groupId>
    <artifactId>filler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>account-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>13</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Simply remove the relativePath.

Comment: and where does it gets his versions ? only by the modules in parent ?

Comment: @Max what do you mean? `relativePath` does not contain a version. You should only remove the `relativePath` element.

Comment: Keep the version, just remove the one element.

Comment: I don't mean the <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
I mean where do I get the versions from the dependencies from the parent pom (only the modules in the parent pom are enough) ?

Comment: `../pom.xml` is the default value for `relativePath` and should actually be fine for the structure you have shown.

Comment: Ok, so normal my code should work, but unfortunate it doesn‘t?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: The second sentence is my error. Or the headline describes it too.

Comment: I can remove the relativePath and there no errors anymore, but it doesn't use the dependencies from the parent pom

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove this tag from child pom.xml by default it will search in parent dir

```
<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
```

Comment: try ../baseapp/pom.xml

Comment: provide folder structure screenshot child pom.xml and parent pom.xml

Comment: added structure picture

Comment: please run this cmd mvn clean install -X  and attached output too

Comment: in your case ../baseapp/pom.xml should be ../filler/pom.xml, please try this

Comment: that's what @leccionesonline said one awnser above

Comment: shared it, "mvn clean install -X"

Comment: no it doesn't show any error, but the code in the pom.xml is marked as an error

Comment: select pom.xml -> right click -> select maven -> update project   Have you tried this already ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205036/discussion-between-sarjit-and-max).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to add to the route the name of the parent project:

```
<relativePath> ../parentclass/pom.xml </relativePath>
```